# Pass pug mixin to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, pug

I have a common modal all over my site for showing endnotes. I wanted to create a quick pug mixin so I don't have to type the structure over and over.

However, I don't know how to pass the #id into my js toggle_visibility function. (Note, the js works perfectly, I'm just trying to convert to a mixin)

```
mixin modal(id, content)
 div.modal(class= id)
  div.modal-content= content
   a.close(onclick="toggle_visibility('= id');") Close
```

Here's an example of the pug code working (outside the mixin)

```
div.modal#downloads-citations
      div.modal-content
        p some content here to show article citations
        a.close(onclick="toggle_visibility('downloads-citations');") Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called 'attribute interpolation', and is not directly supported anymore in current versions of Pug (see [this page](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) in their docs).

Fortunately, however, there is an easy workaround, based on the concatenation of strings. Just replace the last line of your code snippet with this statement:

```
a.close(onclick="toggle_visibility('" + id + "');") Close
```